# Angular 2 Custom Dom Element

Tags: dom, angular, element, custom-element

I have to create something similar to a Facebook 'Like' button. My client would link to some custom javascript and they would put a custom dom element on their page for whatever functionality.

```
<head>
    <script src="www.domain.com/client1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-element></my-element>
</body>
```

I think aot would be perfect for this scenario. Would that be a good assessment?

`client1.js` would be my bundled ng2 files. But what about compatibility? Will this work in all evergreen browsers? What if client1 also has ng2 files linked to their webpage?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do and why are you mentioning AoT? Do you really know what Angular 2 is it does not seem like you would. @CurlyFro

Comment: cool -- i've got it working.  however, in testing and putting the component on a page that already has ng2 i'm getting a zone already defined error.  is there a way to isolate my component so i don't get zone conflicts?